# order a collection through different way

Tags: java, compare

I have this class:

```
public class Paint implements Comparable<Paint>{

  private String cod_paint;
  private String title_paint;
  private String author;
  private int year;

  public Paint(String cod_paint,String title_paint,String author,int year){

    this.cod_paint = cod_paint;
    this.title_paint = title_paint;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
  }

  /* And follow get method */

}
```

Now I would create some object Paint and insert them into a collection for example `ArrayList`

after I have to sort this collection one time by `author`,one other time `year` and once another time for `cod_paint`.

To do this I have to implement inside Paint the method `compareTo`

For instance:

```
public int compareTo(Paint p){

    return cod_paint.compareTo(p.cod_paint);
}
```

in this way when I'll use the method `sort` on my `ArrayList<Paint>` it'll be order by `cod_paint`. But now how can I implement the other way to order (by author,by year) in the same method compareTo?

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `Comparable`, use a custom `Comparator` instead. I'd go with an enum of `Comparator`s:

```
public enum PaintComparator implements Comparator<Paint>{
    BY_NAME{
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Paint left, Paint right){
            return left.getAuthor().compareTo(right.getAuthor());
        }
    },
    // more similar items here
}
```

Now use it as follows:

```
List<Paint> myList = // init list here
Collections.sort(myList, PaintComparator.BY_NAME);
```

See:

- Java Tutorial: [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
- [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: (+1) Nice technique! The two components are quite common, but I've never seen them combined this way.

Comment: but I have to add to my class also Comparable<Paint> ?

Comment: @Mazzy no, only if you don't use a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 2):

If you need different sort orders, it's easier to implement multiple comparators ([`Comparator<Paint>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) and pass the appropriate one to the [`sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) function.

This can also be done in-line using anonymous classes:

```
Collections.sort(my_list, new Comparator<Paint>() {
  public int compare(Paint o1, Paint o2) { ... }
  boolean equals(Object obj) { ... }
});
```